# What return type to use for a method that returns a list of anonymous type?

Tags: c#, linq, list

Doing some refactoring of old code, the developer responsible long having left.

He bequeathed me this bit of Linq:

```
var orders = memberOrders
   .Join(members, x => x.MemberID, y => y.MemberID, (x,y) => new { Order = x , y.MemberName })
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Order.MailingDate).ToList();
```

Which creates some sort of dual value list with an Order object connected to a MemberName string for that object.

I want a function to return this. However, I cannot figure out what type it is that the function needs to return.

Calling `GetType()` reveals it's called `` List`1 ``, which isn't terribly helpful. It looks like a `List<T>` constructed on the fly by the compiler into a custom object.

What is it, and how can I return it from a function?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, hovering over `var` produces a tooltip that explains it all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's returning an list of an anonymous type with two properties: `Order` and `MemberName`.  *Technically* you can return a list of an anonymous type (the return type could be `object` or `List<dynamic>`), but you then require the caller to use reflection or `dynamic` to access the properties.

It's safer to create a new type (or use an existing one) and return a list of *that* instead.

Comment: Great, thanks. Was hoping to do without a custom type for this one call, but ... needs must and all that.

Comment: @MattThrower A custom type would fulfil another important role: expressing what the type is and what it contains via its name and property names. Anonymous types cannot do that.

Comment: I've just re-read my own comments and realised my mind must've gone off on a massive tangent without my fingers. I'm going to delete them because they don't add anything.

Comment: Well if you only use that function in one place maybe you don't need it to be a separate function :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a list of an anonymous type created at:

```
new { Order = x , y.MemberName }
```

Comment: You're not answering the actual question, _"I want a function to return this. However, I cannot figure out what type it is that the function needs to return"_. What return type should OP use?

Answer (score 1):

It's a list of objects of an anonymous type with two properties.

The first property is called `Order` and the second is called `MemberName`.

> I want a function to return this. However, I cannot figure out what
>   type it is that the function needs to return.

It would be more meaningful then, if you could define a class with this two properties and then return a sequence of them. Like below:

```
public class ClassName
{
    public TypeOfOrder Order { get; set; }
    public TypeOfMemberName MemberName { get; set; }   
}
```

Then you declare the method for getting the orders.

```
public IEnumerable<ClassName> GetOrders()
{
   var orders = memberOrders.Join(members, 
                                  x => x.MemberID, 
                                  y => y.MemberID, 
                                 (x,y) => new ClassName 
                                 { 
                                     Order = x,
                                     MemberName = y.MemberName 
                                 }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Order.MailingDate);           
    return orders;
}
```